# Web Automation running in background

Tags: javascript, automation, google-chrome-extension, greasemonkey, userscripts

I'm looking to automate a set of actions on a website. A Sample set of actions would be the following...

```
1. Click on an element (hyperlink)
2. Wait 6000ms
3. Click on a different element (hyperlink)
4. Wait 60000ms
5. Repeat
```

I know many things that can accomplish this task such as iMacro, JAVA's robot class, Selenium, etc.), but all of those programs run in the foreground. I was wondering if there is anyway to implement this while still retaining mouse control ie. the program would run in the background. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: I just realized iMacro has a silent feature. I'm looking into it more but it looks like this is one way to do it. I'm still curious if there are any other ways though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [web workers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/workers.html) and normal JavaScript to do this. Just start a `Worker` on a script and call `dispatchEvent` with a `click` event on the hyperlinks in question.